# how to query file list in the apache http file server with http request

Tags: apache, http

There is one Apache Http Server and there are two files in the path like the below :

> http://{apache-endpoint}/repo/artifacts/file/file-1.2.3/
>
> file1
>   file2

I want to call one http request to get all files in the path.
I try  send http get request with the url

> http://{apache-endpoint}/repo/artifacts/file/file-1.2.3/

just only get one html page. I only want get the two files name.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need directory browsing. Add the following to your website config:

```
<Directory /repo/artifacts/file/file-1.2.3>
    Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have no privilege to change the config.

Comment: You can add the same into websites .htaccess

Comment: Thanks I will let site admin add it.